# Deleting files archived with NSCoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to delete all files that my application has persisted using NSCoding.  Seems like it should be a simple thing to do, but I can't find an answer, whilst I'm showing just one class here, I have several and I'd like the delete function to save all instances of all classes my app has archived.   I'm not doing anything different to NSCoder:

So my interface is defined

```
Details : NSObject <NSCoding>
```

My implementation has:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    NSLog(@"initWithCoder 'Details'");

    if (self = [super init])
    {
        NSLog(@"Decoding 'Details'");

        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    NSLog(@"Encoding 'Details'");
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
}
```

When I write it I'm using:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:data forKey:identifier];
```

I did start off trying to look in the documents directory, but I think as I'm writing this and from my research that it will be written to NSUserDefaults (and that might not be the best thing).   So at the risk of asking two questions, how do I delete all my objects that are saved/archived using NSCoder to NSUserDefaults (and potentially, should I be setting this to something else (i.e a sub-folder inside the documents folder....if yes, how would I do that).

Comment: How big are these data items? You probably shouldn't use `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: @Wain, not massive - small data classes, mostly could be 5 or 6 NSString properties, but sometimes those data classes could be 20 or so in an NSArray.  Guessing NSUserDefaults isn't going to be best place for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSCoding` provides a way to transform objects into `NSData` for easy archiving. What you do with those `NSData` objects afterward are your responsibility. You may or may not save them to individual files, but `NSCoding` is not aware of that.

It seems like you have been dumping those `NSData` into `NSUserDefaults` using `[userDefaults setObject:data forKey:identifier];` 
You need to delete all entries for every `identifier` you have used by doing `[userDefaults removeObjectForKey:identifier];`. 
You can't automatically determine what those entries are.

Additionally, you might want to consider not hogging `NSUserDefaults` and save those to individual files. (look at `[NSData writeToFile:]`) This will additionally help you track what those files are (you could for example all place them in the same folder/subfolder).